# Detecting when an else block gets executed for the second time

Tags: perl

I've a problem in an if-block. I'm comparing two variables, if they are equal then some statements should be executed otherwise some other statement should be executed. **I need to return new statement if my false block is executed second time.**

For example:

```
if($type eq $kind ){
  $line1 .= "</p></list-item>\n<list-item><p>";
}
else{
  $line1 .= "\n<list list-type=\"$kind\">\n<list-item><p>";
}
```

Here `type=bullet` and `kind=number`, now the second time the else part (again `kind=number`) is executed, I want to show the same statement assigned to the $line, I want to show like `<list-item></p>`

Where do I check the condition again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep some state, and use that to determine what to print out the second (or third, or...) time around.

```
my $has_printed_once = 0;

# your loop {

  if ($type eq $kind) {
    # no change
  } else {
    if ($has_printed_once == 0) {
      # print the second thing
    } else {
      $has_printed_once = 1;
      # print the first thing
    }
  }

# } close loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Outside the loop, you can define a state variable.

```
my $state = 1;
```

Inside the loop, test and set the state variable.

```
if($type eq $kind )
{
    $line1 .= "</p></list-item>\n<list-item><p>";
}
else
{
    if( $state eq 1 )
    {
        $line1 .= "\n<list list-type=\"$kind\">\n<list-item><p>";
        $state++ ;
    }
    else
    {
        $line1 .= "(whatever you want to write the second time)";
    }
}
```

Please note this is a fragment of code. I have not run it through the perl interpreter to check for errors. I hope it gives you the idea.